# How to embed an Applet on a JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, applet

I have my applet in a Package called "AppletTabla", the class name is "AppTabla"

I'm using this code to embed it to the JSP page, but I always get an "ClassNotFoundException" when I run the JSP.

```
<APPLET CODE = "AppTabla.class"
        CODEBASE="AppletTabla/"
               WIDTH = "400"
               HEIGHT = "550"
               ALIGN= "BOTTOM"
></APPLET>
```

Also, I've trying to run some examples from different pages, but I keep getting the "NoClassDefFoundError".

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying a relative URL to `codebase`, which means that if your JSP is at "http://www.domain.com/some/path/page.jsp", the applet is expected to be at "http://www.domain.com/some/path/AppletTabla/AppTabla.class".

Try specifying an absolute path for `codebase`, e.g. "/AppletTabla/" or wherever it is.

Comment: "AppletTabla" is in the "WEB-INF/classes" folder (I'm using NetBeans), I tried it this way CODEBASE="WEB-INF/classes/AppletTabla/" and also tried to paste the folder in the same path with the JSP, I get the same "ClassNotFoundException"

Comment: *"AppletTabla" is in the "WEB-INF/classes"*  Whoa!  It should not be in an area for private resources!

Comment: The URL specified in `codebase` needs to be publicly accessible, and the `.class` file needs to be in that location, and you need to be mindful of absolute vs. relative paths. A path that does not *start* with a "/" (or a URL scheme) is *relative*!

Comment: Ok, now I have the folder in the exact same path as the JSP, and my codebase is now set to CODEBASE="/AppletTabla/". There's something wrong?

Comment: What is the full path to your JSP?

Comment: this: "\NetBeansProjects\AppletExample\build\web\index.jsp"

Comment: And your applet is "\NetBeansProjects\AppletExample\build\web\AppletTabla\AppTabla.class", with `codebase="AppletTabla/"` (no leading "/")?

Comment: Yes, it is there. with codebase="/AppletTabla/" and codebase="AppletTabla/" I get the same error

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace of the error in your question?

Comment: I just get a message box, it says "NoClassDefFoundError - AppTabla (wrong name: AppletTabla/AppTabla)"